# Threaded generalised transform

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm writing an application which works with huge amounts of sequential data, and often found the need to use `std::transform`. I see two potential improvements to `std::transform`:

1. Allow for variable number parameters.
2. Take advantage of the linear separability of the data by multithreading.

Can anyone suggest any design/performance improvements on my implementation?

**threaded_transform.h**

```
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

template<typename InputIterator, typename OutputIterator,
         typename Function, typename... Params>
OutputIterator
trans(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, OutputIterator result,
          Function f, Params... params)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first, ++result)
        *result = f(*first, params...);
    return result;
}

template<typename InputIterator, typename OutputIterator,
         typename Function, typename... Params>
OutputIterator
threaded_transform(unsigned num_threads, InputIterator first,
                   InputIterator last, OutputIterator result,
                   Function f, Params... params)
{
    std::size_t num_values = last - first;
    std::size_t num_values_per_threads = num_values / num_threads;

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    threads.reserve(num_threads);

    for (unsigned i = 1; i <= num_threads; ++i) {
        if (i == num_threads) {
            // The last thread processes the remaining values.
            threads.push_back(std::thread(trans<InputIterator, OutputIterator, Function, Params...>,
                                          first, last, result, f, params...));
        } else {
            threads.push_back(std::thread(trans<InputIterator, OutputIterator, Function, Params...>,
                                          first, first + num_values_per_threads, result, f, params...));
        }
        first  += num_values_per_threads;
        result += num_values_per_threads;
    }

    for (auto& thread : threads)
        thread.join();

    return result;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <vector>
#include "threaded_transform.h"

int main()
{
    auto sum = [] (int a, int b) { return a + b; };

    std::vector<int> values = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    std::vector<int> results;
    results.resize(10);

    threaded_transform(4, values.cbegin(), values.cend(), results.begin(), sum, 10);

    for (auto result : results) {
        std::cout << result << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to forward your parameters:

```
   *result = f(*first, params...);
```

Try:

```
   *result = f(*first, std::forward<Params>(params)...);
```

To go along with forwardign you probably want two versions of `trans()` on that takes values by reference/value one that takes r-value references:

```
// Normal parameters.
trans(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, OutputIterator result,
      Function f, Params const&... params)

// R-Value parameters.
trans(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, OutputIterator result,
      Function f, Params&&... params)
```

Going to main transform function.

I am not sure you in realty want to pass a function and arguments. That's the whole point of the lambda. So you can wrap the function call and its parameters into a function.

```
threaded_transform(4, values.cbegin(), values.cend(), results.begin(), sum, 10);

// Or would you prefer:

threaded_transform(4, values.cbegin(), values.cend(), results.begin(),
    [](int other){ return add(other, 10);}
);

//Or even
threaded_transform(4, values.cbegin(), values.cend(), results.begin(),
    [](int other){ return 10 + other;}
);
```

If you do this you should write details about your iterator requirements.

The requirements for `std::transform()`

```
template<class InputIterator1, class InputIterator2, class OutputIterator, class BinaryFunction>
OutputIterator transform(InputIterator1 first1, InputIterator1 last1,
                         InputIterator2 first2, OutputIterator result,
                         BinaryFunction binary_op);


Where:
   InputIterator must be a model of Input Iterator.
   OutputIterator must be a model of Output Iterator.
```

In your threaded implementation you have a more stringent requirement for the output iterator. I believe it needs to be random access iterator.

```
    OutputIterator must be a model of Random Access Iterator.
```

See: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/RandomAccessIterator.html

Answer (score 3):

- `std::size_t num_values_per_threads = num_values / num_threads;`
  This may unbalance the workload. say we have `11` elements and **4** threads. `11` / **4** = 2. Workload for thread **0**, **1**, **2** is `2` elements, for thread **3** it is `5` elements. The last thread has the most work limiting the total throughput.
  Additionally you are wasting a thread by making it wait for the futures and doing no actual work. I recommend something like 
  `std::size_t num_values_per_threads = (num_values + num_threads - 1) / num_threads;`
  This gives us `num_values_per_threads` = `3` with a rest of `2` for the calling thread before it joins with the thread handles. Since the last thread starts last it is probably a good idea to give it a little bit less work to have everyone finish roughly at the same time.
- Providing the number of threads to launch is old and boring. The new hotness is to let the runtime system figure that out. Pseudo-code:

  ```
  parallel_transform(begin_range, end_range)
  {
      auto future = async(parallel_transform, begin_range, mid_range);
      parallel_transform(mid_range, end_range);
  }
  ```

  This should launch as many threads as the hardware can handle without specifying the number explicitly. It is a quality of implementation thing though, there is a chance that you do not get any concurrency with this.
- Why do you use `trans` instead of `std::transform`? As far as I can tell they do the same thing and `std::transform` is more familiar and less difficult to understand that `trans`.
- `std::size_t num_values = last - first;`
  This requires random access iterators. It would be nice to make it work with forward iterators so you can use `threaded_transform` on `std::list`s. This is a bit more work though.
- Prefer free standing `begin` and `end` instead of member functions. `values.cbegin()` -> `cbegin(values)`. The reason is that C-style arrays and some use defined containers do not have member functions `begin` and `end` and especially not `cbegin` and `cend`. However, it is usually easy to provide a free function overload for them, so the free function version is more consistent.
- You forgot `#include <iostream>` for `std::cout`.
- What you are trying to do is being proposed to the standard under the names `Parallelism TS` and `Parallel STL` and is in the process of getting into the C++ standard. You can find [some experimental](https://parallelstl.codeplex.com/) [implementations online](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=parallel_transform). There is a good chance every compiler's STL implementation has that by 2017. You are just a bit ahead of the standard. Good :D